# PHP Regex Match URL with Specific Link Text

Tags: php, regex

I'm having issues matching a specific link with regex.

The link's title looks like this:  [*italicized* —  Some More Words (1234)](http://google.com)

I'm using this regex expression, but it's not finding any matches:

```
<a href=\"([^\"]*)\"><em>italicized<\/em> &mdash; Some More Words ([0-9]{4})<\/a>
```

Additionally, the numbers portion of the link title can vary, thus the reason for the number capture group.

Comment: Please give a sample of the actual HTML you want to match.

Comment: So the numbers can vary, but `italicized` and `Some More Words` are the exact and fixed labels?

Comment: @mario, yes, the `italicized` and `Some More Words` do not change.

Comment: Well, then your example regex would match the above example link except for the capture parens (not literals).

Comment: Hmmm...Here's the regex on a live tester: http://regex101.com/r/vZ9zO1/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parens `(` and `)` are meta characters for capture groups.

They won't match literal paranthesis in the source text. For that they had to be escaped.